# HID (Human Interface Device) - send keys CMD+SPACE

Tags: bluetooth, escaping, hid

I want to use HID to send the keyboard shortcut `CMD+SPACE` to the mac, which opens Spotlight. So I need the CMD to be a hold key, and the space to trigger the shortcut. How do I do this? I am using the LightBlue bean, which communicates via Bluetooth to the mac using HID protocol. An example that is working for me elsewhere is:

```
BeanHid.sendKeys("/dnd "); //turn do not disturb off if it is on
BeanHid.sendKeys("\r\n"); //return / newline
```

The reference for the lightblue bean's HID class is here:

https://punchthrough.com/files/bean/arduino-core-docs/1.8.0-beta1/class_bean_hid__.html#a40083ffe2f60453c9988419b083a26ad

I'm guessing I need the `holdKey`, `sendKey`, and `releaseKey` methods. But what I need is whatever keycodes signify a cmd and space.

Answer (score 1):

The Apple "Command" key, the Windows "Windows" key and the Linux "Super" key are all represented by the USB "GUI" key modifier bits.

There are two of these: Left GUI and Right GUI. The space key is simply the USB "Spacebar" usage. So you would need to build and send, for example, the "Left GUI" modifier + "Spacebar" in your buffer.

The exact contents of that buffer depends on the HID report descriptor you are using, but for the following fairly typical keyboard report descriptor:

```
05 01        (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0001 Generic Desktop Page 
09 06        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x00010006 Keyboard (CA=Application Collection) 
A1 01        (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x00000001 Application (Usage=0x00010006: Page=Generic Desktop Page, Usage=Keyboard, Type=CA)
05 07          (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0007 Keyboard/Keypad Page 
19 E0          (LOCAL)  USAGE_MINIMUM      0x000700E0 Keyboard Left Control (DV=Dynamic Value) 
29 E7          (LOCAL)  USAGE_MAXIMUM      0x000700E7 Keyboard Right GUI (DV=Dynamic Value) 
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0)
25 01          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x01 (1)  
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field  
95 08          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x08 (8) Number of fields  
81 02          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000002 (8 fields x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
95 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields  
75 08          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field  
81 01          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000001 (1 field x 8 bits) 1=Constant 0=Array 0=Absolute 
95 05          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x05 (5) Number of fields  
75 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x01 (1) Number of bits per field  
05 08          (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0008 LED Indicator Page 
19 01          (LOCAL)  USAGE_MINIMUM      0x00080001 Num Lock (OOC=On/Off Control) 
29 05          (LOCAL)  USAGE_MAXIMUM      0x00080005 Kana (OOC=On/Off Control) 
91 02          (MAIN)   OUTPUT             0x00000002 (5 fields x 1 bit) 0=Data 1=Variable 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
95 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields  
75 03          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x03 (3) Number of bits per field  
91 01          (MAIN)   OUTPUT             0x00000001 (1 field x 3 bits) 1=Constant 0=Array 0=Absolute 0=NoWrap 0=Linear 0=PrefState 0=NoNull 0=NonVolatile 0=Bitmap 
95 06          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x06 (6) Number of fields  
75 08          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x08 (8) Number of bits per field  
25 65          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x65 (101)  
05 07          (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x0007 Keyboard/Keypad Page 
19 00          (LOCAL)  USAGE_MINIMUM      0x00070000 Keyboard No event indicated (Sel=Selector) 
29 65          (LOCAL)  USAGE_MAXIMUM      0x00070065 Keyboard Application (Sel=Selector) 
81 00          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000000 (6 fields x 8 bits) 0=Data 0=Array 0=Absolute 
C0           (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Application
```

...the buffer representing LeftGUI modifier + Spacebar would be (in hex):

```
08 2C
```

Alternatively, you could send RightGUI modifier + Spacebar:

```
80 2C
```

After sending one of the above, you need to indicate that no keys are pressed by then sending a "no keys pressed" buffer:

```
00 00
```

It's worth noting that the 2C is an index (between LOGICAL_MINIMUM 0x00 to LOGICAL_MAXIMUM 0x65) into the array of USAGES from USAGE_MINIMUM (0x00) to USAGE_MAXIMUM (0x65) that you defined in your HID Report Descriptor and not the actual usage code within the keyboard usage page (which is 0x0007002C).

If you only ever want to indicate that the spacebar is pressed you could code USAGE 0007002C, LOGICAL_MINIMUM 1, LOGICAL_MAXIMUM 1 in your HID Report Descriptor and then send:

```
80 01
```

...to indiate that the spacebar (and GUI modifier) are currently pressed, followed by:

```
00 00
```

...to indicate that no keys are currently pressed.

Comment: This was helpful - but doesn't seem to be something I can use in HID protocol (or at least not through Lightblue Bean's sendKeys method.

Comment: If you can get a packet capture (using wireshark for example) of the handshake as you plug the device in you can analyse the HID report descriptor to find out if they support the Space key usage...then you can just send the index for that usage - after calling holdKey(KEY_LEFT_GUI)